# Need a way to return value from many columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], 
                    'Qty': [1, 3, 5, 6, 1]})
```

that looks like this

```
       Name  Qty
    0    A    1
    1    B    3
    2    C    5
    3    A    6
    4    D    1
```

I need to create a new column 'Rate' in `df1` that contains values from `df2` such that the match is made both by Qty and Name.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Qty': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'A': [1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0],
                    'B': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6],
                    'C': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.2, 3.0],
                    'D': [1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9]})
```

that looks like

```
        Qty  A    B    C    D
    0    1  1.0  1.1  0.5  1.4
    1    2  1.2  1.2  1.0  1.5
    2    3  1.4  1.3  1.5  1.6
    3    4  1.6  1.4  2.0  1.7
    4    5  1.8  1.5  2.2  1.8
    5    6  2.0  1.6  3.0  1.9
```

Resulting df3 should look like this

```
df3    
      Name  Qty  Rate
    0    A    1   1.0
    1    B    3   1.3
    2    C    5   2.2
    3    A    6   2.0
    4    D    1   1.4
```

Baically search df2 with 'coordinates' given in df1 and return the value.

Comment: `df2` has 4 values, which one of them should become `Rate`?

Comment: The deprecated `lookup` function again. The doc has an alternative [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup).

Comment: Since `lookup` is deprecated, look at the other two (non-accepted) answers in the dup link.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) followed by [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to do this.

Code Example:

```py
df2_reformated = df2.melt(id_vars=['Qty'], var_name='Name', value_name='Rate')
df3 = df1.merge(df2_reformated)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Qty  Rate
0    A    1   1.0
1    B    3   1.3
2    C    5   2.2
3    A    6   2.0
4    D    1   1.4
```

This works by converting the df2 variable from 'wide' to 'long format. For example, the first few rows of the dataframe, after melting, would look like this:

```
    Qty Name  Rate
0     1    A   1.0
1     2    A   1.2
2     3    A   1.4
```

Once you have it in this format, you can use merge() to combine it with df1. merge() works by looking at the columns in common between two dataframes, and combining rows which match in those columns.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

(i) create a MultiIndex from `df1`: `idx`

(ii) `set_index` of `df2` to `Qty` and `unstack`. This creates a MultiIndex Series. Using `idx` filter the relevant rows:

```
idx = df1.set_index(['Name','Qty']).index
out = df2.set_index('Qty').unstack().loc[idx].reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Rate'})
```

Output:

```
  Name  Qty  Rate
0    A    1   1.0
1    B    3   1.3
2    C    5   2.2
3    A    6   2.0
4    D    1   1.4
```